# javascript form validation Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

My form isn't validating; when I submit the form it just clears, even if it isn't filled out right. I have searched around for different ways to validate this, and this is the least complicated. I've tried others and I get the same thing no matter what.

```
function validate() {
    var fname=document.myForm.fName;
    var lname=document.myForm.lName;
    var age=document.myForm.uAge;
    var uname=document.myForm.userName;
    var email=document.myForm.eMail;
    var pass=document.myForm.password;
    var rpass=document.myForm.repass;
    var disp=document.myForm.display;
    var udate=document.myForm.update;
    if(fname.value < 3) {
        window.alert("First name must be atleast 3 characters!");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(lname.value < 3) {
        window.alert("Last name must be atleast 3 characters!");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(age.value < 14 || > 110) {
        window.alert("You must be between ages 14 & 110");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(uname.value < 5) {
        window.alert("You must have a user name of 5 characters!");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(email.value.indexOf("@", 0) < 0) {
        window.alert("Email Invalid!");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(email.value.indexOf(".", 0) < 0) {
        window.alert("Email Invalid!");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(pass.value < 8) {
        window.alert("Password must be 8 characters long");
        pass.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(rpass.value !=pass) {
        window.alert("Passwords do not match!);
        rpass.focus();
        return();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menubar">
<a href="homepage.html" class="button">Home</a>
<a href="lucyreview.html" class="button">Lucy</a>
<a href="insurgentreview.html" class="button">Insurgent</a>
<a href="almanacreview.html" class="button">Proj.Almanac</a>
<a href="registryForm.html" class="button">Register</a>
</div>

<div id="registry">
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate())">
<table cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="2px" border="1px">
<tr><td>First Name: </td><td><input name="fName" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" required /></td></tr>

<tr><td>Last Name: </td><td><input name="lName" type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required /></td></tr>

<tr><td>Age: </td><td><input name="uAge" type="number" placeholder="Enter your Age" required /></td></tr>

<tr><td>User Name: </td><td><input name="uName" type="text" placeholder="Enter desired User Name" required/></td></tr>

<tr><td>Email: </td><td><input type="eMail" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email address" required /></td></tr>

<tr><td>Password(8 Char.): </td><td><input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter 8 character Password" required /></td></tr>

<tr><td>Re-Enter Password: </td><td><input name="rePass" type="password" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" required /></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="display">Check to display info to public</td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="updates" />Check to recieve updates</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="validate()" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" onclick="changeBack()">
<button type="button" onclick="backgroundChange()">Set background color</button>
```

Comment: `window.alert("Passwords do not match!);` <- a quote missing here? after "match!"

Comment: There’s at least two more errors of different types, see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32160244/2083613).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s at least these three changes you should make, since they are syntax errors:

```
if(age.value < 14 || > 110)
// ⬇ missing operand
if(age.value < 14 || age.value > 110)

window.alert("Passwords do not match!);
// ⬇ missing "
window.alert("Passwords do not match!");

return();
// ⬇ not function but keyword
return;
```

Comment: ok i made those changes but still don't get any alerts when fields aren't filled out correctly

Comment: Your question was about an `Uncaught SyntaxError`, and the above answer _solved_ these issues. Please note that Stack Overflow is no code writing or debugging service. Just open your browser's inspector, its console will show you the other, obvious errors. Also, remember what to do [when someone answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).